# Book about axe-wielding protagonist who goes berserk in battle and blinds a woman

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been searching for this book for at least 6 years now. I don't remember much at all about it, but maybe you guys can help me.

I have no idea the plot, but I remember the protagonist being male and axe-wielding. At one point, he is battling a FEW men (or ogres?) and he goes berserk. Red vision and all crazy. He wins the battle and realizes, after the fact, that he hit the woman he was helping (or maybe she was just in the way?) with his axe while going crazy. I'm not sure how the scene ends, but I think he leaves her for dead. Later, they meet again and she is still alive - blinded because of him.

For some reason, I'm thinking she either became a warrior or ended up a slave to those type of people that the berserker guy defeated in battle.

I think the cover had the both of them on it and it was drawn in a realistic style. It wasn't a comic strip - it was definitely a full book. I know it was without pictures.

Comment: Could that possibly be a Thrud the Barbarian comic strip? Thrud accidentally whacking the damsel he was "saving" would be very likely.

Comment: Was his battleaxe a curved blade on a short chain?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry! I got busy and forgot to check back! No, it wasn't a comic strip - it was definitely a full book. I know it was without pictures. I really don't remember much, but now that I'm a bit older, haha, I'd like to reread it.

Comment: @Danny3414 I'm not sure about the axe! :/ That's a great question. I don't remember many details. I'm sorry I'm not of more help with that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Everquest: Truth and Steel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159315223X)* by Thomas M. Reid

[image: Cover of *Truth and Steel* showing Khaniel and Zethamy]

> Khaniel Devlin, weapons master and mercenary, encounters a troupe of Paladins seeking the hidden refuge of a long-lost member of their order. Led by a devout and charismatic woman named Zethamy Demarro, the group is attacked by a horde of giant cyclopes and Khaniel accidentally cuts Zethamy down during the ferocious battle. Khaniel and his dwarven friend Bruigan are hauled back home to Freeport in irons where they are ultimately sold into slavery in the ogre city of Oggok.In captivity Khaniel discovers that Zethamy did not perish that fateful day in the mountains, but lost her sight and is now also a slave among the ogres. Khaniel, Bruigan and their new shaman friend, Bhaobuk mount a rescue mission and soon are running for their lives in the wilds, with the blind but determined Zethamy in tow. Still intent upon finding the elusive hermit who is in possession of invaluable religious treasures, she persuades Khaniel to help her track down the recluse's lair. But danger awaits the small band as they soon discover that powerful foes are on the same quest...

Comment: UGH you are amazing! This is it! Thank youuuuu!

Answer (score 1):

*[The Legend](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/618177.Legend)* by David Gemmell

[image: Book cover - *Legend*]

> He is DRUSS the Legend. His skill in battle has earned him a fearsome reputation throughout the world and the stories of his life are told everywhere. But the grizzled veteran has spurned a life of fame and fortune and has retreated to the solitude of his mountain lair to await his old enemy, Death.
>
> Meanwhile, barbarian hordes of the Nadir are on the march, conquering all before them. All that stands before them and victory is the legendary six-walled fortress of the Drenai empire, Dros Delnoch. If the fortress falls, so do the Drenai. Druss reluctantly agrees to come out of retirement. But can even Druss live up to his own legends?

Comment: Hi there! :) Could you please [edit] into your answer the elements from thebook which make you think this is the one?

Comment: I don't recall Druss ever blinding a woman, even by accident...

Comment: Maybe one of the Legends of the Nameless Dwarf by D.P.Prior?

Comment: No Druss kills a couple of women he wishes he hadn't, in his first life and later but Snaga only goes exactly where he wants it to.